How to execute the method passed as an Expression<Action<T>> argument?
I have a class in a .netcore aplication which is used to enqueu background tasks:
public interface IBackgroundTasksService {
  void RunBackgroundTask<T>(Expression<Action<T>> methodCall);
}

public class BackgroundTasksService : IBackgroundTasksService {
  public void RunBackgroundTask<T>(Expression<Action<T>> methodCall){
   // calls to the Backgorund service worker thrid party library with `methodCall` as a param.
   // this works as expected
  }
}

When called by other services, this is the usual pattern:
_backgroundTasksService.RunBackgroundTask<MyService>(x => x.Execute(id, name, color));

This is the issue: When running Unit tests I need the methodCall to be called instead of having it logged for the backgound worker, so I created a stub for the BackgroundTasksService:
public class BackgroundTasksServiceStub : IBackgroundTasksService {
  public void RunBackgroundTask<T>(Expression<Action<T>> methodCall){
    Expression.Lambda(methodCall).Compile().DynamicInvoke(); // this is just one of the attempts (it does not work)

  }
}

I have tried a few different approaches, but I am yet to see one that makes the call to MyService.Execute ...
What would be an approach for executing the argument method?

why DynamicInvoke,  when you know the actions type at compile-time? Compile returns Action<T>, so you can either call Invoke or even shorter directly use Compile()(myInstanceOfT), whatever that instance is.

How do you get the instance of the service?

That was just a sily attempt (otherwise the method would be empty on the question) I am not familiar enough with these expressions to make a semsible one.

I assume the instance of MyService comes from Dependency Injection (as that is the only place the service is created). But as this is a Third party`s lib (hangfire) I think it is fair to assume it comes from DI

Thanks to the comments from the question I got it to work!
This is how the working stub class goes:
public class BackgroundTasksServiceStub : IBackgroundTasksService {
  private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

  public BackgroundTasksServiceStub(IServiceProvider serviceProvider){
    _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
  }

  public void RunBackgroundTask<T>(Expression<Action<T>> methodCall){
    var service = _serviceProvider.GetService<T>();
    var method = methodCall.Compile();
    method(service);
  }
}

